# How do I pass the commit SHA as a parameter in GITLab WebHook

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I want to trigger a Jenkins Job if there is code commit made to Gitlab

I am using WebHooks for this:
[image]

The URL I am trying is

```
http://10.192.39.32:1024/job/SCMSnaps/buildWithParameters?token=secretkey&SNAP=$GIT_COMMIT
```

I want SNAP to hold the value of the SHA Number on the Gitlab

can anyone help with the correct way to pass variables in a WebHook URL?

Comment: The commit hash is in the payload GitLab sends. As far as I am aware you can't pass parameters in the URL. Jenkins has a special integration for GitLab so it can read the POST Payload. As for SNAP I don't know.

Comment: @Fairy:
We can pass parameters in URL.
The above URL just does that, 
I want that parameter to be a variable like $GIT_COMMIT

Comment: What Fairy is saying is that Gitlab cannot set the parameters in the URL, only in the post payload. The webhook can also be triggered for a comment for example, how would it set this parameter in that case ? You have to interpret the POST payload within jenkins to get the commit hash.

Answer (score 1):

You should install the gitlab hook plugin for jenkins, it will allow you to do just what you want :
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gitlab+Hook+Plugin