# Read webhook payload in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, webhooks, gitlab-ci, git-webhooks

I have a project (`PROJECT_A`) that is triggered through a webhook, and expects the variable `$PRODUCT` to be set. Its value is used to trigger a certain path in the build. The job in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like this:

```
deploy:
  stage: publish
  script:
    - ./generate_doc.sh $PRODUCT
```

A webhook call looks like this:

```
http://<GITLAB_URL>/api/v4/projects/710/ref/master/trigger/pipeline?token=<TOKEN>&variables[PRODUCT]=<PRODUCT>
```

I call this trigger through a webhook from other projects, including `PROJECT_B`.
So I manually filled in the desired value in the respective webhooks, e.g. for `PROJECT_B`:

```
http://<GITLAB_URL>/api/v4/projects/710/ref/master/trigger/pipeline?token=<TOKEN>&variables[PRODUCT]=PROJECT_B
```

When the pipeline in `PROJECT_A` is triggered, `$PRODUCT` has the value `PROJECT_B`, as expected.

I would like to parameterize the pipeline further and take, among others, the commit message into account. All the information I need is apparently provided in the [webhook payload](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#push-events).

Is there a built-in way to read this payload in a [pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines.html)? Or alternatively, put contents of the payload into a variable in the webhook like this:

```
http://<GITLAB_URL>/api/v4/projects/710/ref/master/trigger/pipeline?token=<TOKEN>&variables[COMMIT_REF]=???
```

I have found [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022983/read-json-payload-from-gitlab-webhook-in-jenkins) about doing [parameterized Jenkins builds](https://github.com/elvanja/jenkins-gitlab-hook-plugin#parameterized-projects) using the webhook payload, including [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271430/how-do-i-pass-the-commit-sha-as-a-parameter-in-gitlab-webhook). There is also a [similar question in the Gitlab forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/extract-webhook-payload-in-gitlab-ci/21253), without any answer.

Is there a way to do access that payload in a Gitlab CI pipeline? I could probably extract the provided values with a `jq` call, but how can I get the Json in the first place?

Comment: Any success figuring this out?

Comment: No, I could not parameterize further. The variables are now fixed in the Webhook call, e.g. `http://.../ref/master/trigger/pipeline?token=<...>&variables[PRODUCT]=PROJECT_A`. The triggered project has a script that handles the variable values.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `compgen -v` to show the environment variables when triggering the pipeline in the UI (without JSON payload) you get 3 fewer lines in your job log than when `POST`ing a JSON payload.

The additional variables are:

- `CI_BUILD_TRIGGERED`
- `CI_PIPELINE_TRIGGERED`
- `TRIGGER_PAYLOAD`

If you print their values out and re-run the pipeline:

```sh
echo CI_BUILD_TRIGGERED=$CI_BUILD_TRIGGERED
echo CI_PIPELINE_TRIGGERED=$CI_PIPELINE_TRIGGERED
echo TRIGGER_PAYLOAD=$TRIGGER_PAYLOAD
```

You get (for username YOUR_USER_NAME and repo name YOUR_REPO_NAME)

```
CI_BUILD_TRIGGERED=true
CI_PIPELINE_TRIGGERED=true
TRIGGER_PAYLOAD=/builds/YOUR_USER_NAME/YOUR_REPO_NAME.tmp/TRIGGER_PAYLOAD
```

So as you can see the payload is stored as `TRIGGER_PAYLOAD` in a temporary directory suffixed `.tmp`, which re-running the pipeline and printing it out (`cat`) shows it contains the payload, in my case that’s JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have developed something very unique, it's practically guaranteed that the data provided in the webhook's payload is in JSON format. Gitlab automatically treats received payload data as a FILE type variable. The data is always stored in $TRIGGER_PAYLOAD, and its contents can be manipulated with `cat` and `jq`.

Gitlab's default runner for jobs is based on Alpine, and they already include `jq` as part of the setup. And because jobs' scripts are bash commands, getting the data out is pretty straight forward. If you're using a different image for your jobs, Ubuntu, or something, you can easily install `jq` in your pipeline's `before_script` section. For example, On my website when a new user signs up for a service, I have a webhook that sends that event data to my gitlab repo and creates a project folder.

```
setup_new_user:
  before_script:
    # Install jq, if necessary
    - apt-get install -y jq
  script:
    # Retrieve data from the webhook payload
    - WEBHOOK_BODY=$(cat $TRIGGER_PAYLOAD)
    - NEW_MEMBER_EMAIL=$(echo $WEBHOOK_BODY | jq -r '.members[0].email')
    - etc
```